# Outer merging two dataframes where one contains a StringArray raises ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to perform an outer (or left) merge on two dataframes, the latter of which has an exclusive column with a dtype of "StringDtype", and this raises an error like `ValueError: StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA`.  I understand that I can use `Series.astype(str)` to cast the column to the "object" dtype, but the dataframe has many of these columns and it seems unnecessary to me. I'm wondering if this is a bug or is there another workaround I'm not aware of.

Here is an example to recreate the error:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=pd.Series([1], dtype=int)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=pd.Series([], dtype=int), first_name=pd.Series([], dtype="string")))
df_final = df1.merge(df2, on="id", how="outer") # "outer" can be replaced with "left" with the same effect
```

This *should* result in a DataFrame with a single row containing the id of `1` and the first_name `NA` or something similar, instead it raises the `ValueError`.

This will work if I cast the "first_name" column to "Object" with `df2.first_name = df2.first_name.astype(str)` but I'd like to avoid this as I explained in the first paragraph.

Pandas version 1.0.5 is installed.

Comment: this is happening because you doesn't tell pandas to do outer join on which basis i.e try  passing `on` parameter and pass the column which are common in both df's or if the columns are of different names then pass `left_on` and `right_on` parameters on the basis of which you are joining 2 tables **for example** in `database` you write `outer join users on users.id=post.userid` so here in pandas write `df1.merge(df2, how="outer",left_on='id',right_on='userid')`

Comment: @AnuragDabas Thanks for your comment. I made a typo and missed the "on" argument, it still raises the error with the correct "on" argument.

Comment: which pandas version you are using?

Comment: I've updated the question with the version of pandas (1.0.5)

Comment: ohh that's why you are getting error...I am using pandas 1.2.2 and when i write this `df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=pd.Series([], dtype=int), first_name=pd.Series([])))` it basically gives me `DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning` so by default its converting `df2` to `object` as it is an empty `Series`

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much for that insight, I'll be testing it out shortly!